# What is 1h16 as a time expression?

Tags: time

1Q16 is the first quarter 2016, then what is 1h16?

I guess it's a expression for time. But I have no idea what it is.

Comment: ***First half*** (six months) of 2016! ***Half***: *either of the two equal or nearly equal parts that together make up a whole:* She was born in the latter half of the 18th century. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/half

Comment: First Half 2015 Results: http://www.adidas-group.com/en/media/news-archive/press-releases/2015/first-half-2015-results/

Comment: I would read it as a duration of 1 hour & 16 minutes; or possibly 16 minutes past 1 o'clock.

Comment: @Josh61 I've never seen "h" used as a contraction of "half"; let alone "1h" used as a contraction of "first half".  Nor can I find that usage in the dictionary ref. you've provided.  Is that a common US contraction?

Comment: In business usage it is very common, but I realize  that outside that context it may look queer.

Comment: I've seen it in a firm's annual report. That why I use 1Q16 as an example! Thank you!

Comment: Neither is a standard abbreviation. In media jargon, nQm is often used to signify the nth quarter of the year m. Everything that the media comes up with from time to time is not necessarily part of the English language, but serves to save space for the publisher and time for the reader. HTH.

Comment: I think this is a NARQ in its present form.

Answer (score 1):

Here in Quebec, Canada, we use a 24 hour clock notation to avoid ambiguity.

Sixteen minutes past one o'clock in the morning according to that notation would be 1h16.

Comment: It's a commonly seen way to write time on various parts of the world. Not sure how it cropped up in English though as I don't think any Anglophone region uses it, but it's probably the only way I could see myself reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Haha.  That is highly ambiguous.  In some places, it would mean 01:16, that is, 16 minutes after 1 in the morning.  In other places, it would mean "The first half of 2016".

Comment: Hoho. Note that "avoid" does not imply eliminate. 1:16 could be either 1h16 or 13h16. Would you agree that cutting possibilities in half is *avoiding* ambiguity, at least?

Comment: @Stan -- "1:16" is ambiguous but "01:16" has only one interpretation.  I often see "01 h 16" ("01:16" sense) in the  in the Far East, but paired with "1Q16", well, I would need more context.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context, I'd think it means the "first half of 2016," at least in financial reporting. In addition to the context, the punctuation is key:
1h16 = 1:16 p.m.
1H:16 = First half of 2016.

Comment: Rather than the punctuation (1Q16 has none), the use of a capital is more likely to distiguish. 1H16 is different from 1h16.